# Simple limit question with vector norms

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $x\in \Bbb{R}^2$. What is the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x_1}{\Vert x \Vert}$$

Is it really zero because ; If $x\to 0$, then each $x_i \to 0$ also? Do we need to consider $x_1 >0$  and the case where $x_1<0$?

Comment: What happens if you take the sequence $x_n=1/n\cdot e_1$? And what if $x_n=1/n\cdot e_2$?

Comment: The limit does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

I'd start by writing this out in terms of two variables $(x,y)$:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
$$

As $(x,y)$ approaches the origin, can you see how the relative magnitudes of $x$ and $y$ impact this limit? What happens if we approach the origin much faster in $x$ coordinate than in $y$ coordinate, for instance? (That is, if $x$ is orders of magnitude smaller than $y$.). What if the reverse holds?  What if $x$ and $y$ are linearly related?

Try out a few specific paths and see if the answer depends on the path you choose.  If it does, then the limit doesn't exist.